# Two touching surfaces transmitting light: Name of effect

Tags: optics, visible-light

When two surfaces are sufficiently close enough to each other, light travels through the remaining gap as if it did not exist. Effects like total internal reflection no longer occurs.

If you look at this candle picture, you can see where the wax "touches" the glass and where it doesn't.

https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Bolsius-103422531800-Starlight-Candle-Transparent/dp/B009S95N1A

I know this physical effect has a strange name but I can't seem to find it by Googling it. What's the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sound like you are describing an evanescent wave.